# What is the difference between the full name and the abbreviation of a time zone

Tags: java, timezone, java-time

I have multiple times in my database that look like this:

```
String summerTime = "2022-07-21T10:00:00Z";
String winterTime = "2022-11-21T10:00:00Z";
```

In another hand, I want to get the time part of these dates based on a custom timezone, the timezones that I have, look like this:

```
GMT-03:00
GMT-02:00
GMT-01:00
GMT+02:00
GMT+01:00
....
```

When I try to extract the time part using this code:

```
ZoneId tz = ZoneId.of("GMT+01:00");

ZonedDateTime date1 = ZonedDateTime.parse(summerTime).withZoneSameInstant(tz.toZoneId());
ZonedDateTime date2 = ZonedDateTime.parse(winterTime).withZoneSameInstant(tz.toZoneId());
```

I get:

```
11:00
11:00
```

But if you notice well, the time is the same even on summer or winter dates.

I expect to get:

```
12:00  // <----- correct
11:00  // <----- correct
```

---

I found a solution for my issue, which is using the full name of the time zone, instead of the abbreviation:

```
ZoneId tz = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
```

This gives me the correct response:

```
12:00
11:00
```

**but I can't use this because I should use only the abbreviation.**

My question:

- Why do the two formats give different results?
- How can get the full name from the abbreviation so I can get the correct output?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. For a fixed GMT offset use `ZoneOffset`. For a real (named) time zone use `ZoneId`. The distinction between the two will also make your code clearer and perhaps even answer your question?

Comment: Definitions: An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal prime meridian of UTC. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians. A proper time zone name has a format of `Continent/Region` such as `Africa/Tunis` and `Asia/Tokyo`.

Comment: @BasilBourque nice explanation, It can be a good answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why do the two formats gives different result?

Because your first form is a "fixed offset" time zone, effectively. "GMT+01:00" is *always* on UTC+1, for the whole of time. It doesn't actually map to any specific area of the world, it's just "always UTC+1".

> How can get the full name from the abbreviation so I can get the correct output?

You can't. Even if you know the UTC offset at a particular instant in time, there may be multiple time zones that have that UTC offset at that instant, but have *different* UTC offsets from each other at different times.

For example, currently both Europe/London and Africa/Abidjan are on UTC+0... but in June 2022 (for example) Africa/Abidjan was still be UTC+0, and Europe/London was UTC+1.

> I can't use this because I should use only the abbreviation.

That's a fundamental problem, and you should push back on the requirement. It's like saying "I really need the user's full name, but I only have their initials." It's an infeasible requirement.

Comment: I understand better now, I should change my logic then, thank you Jon

Comment: I think *every answer* dealing with timezone weirdness should always include a link to this old Tom Scott video: https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY – the next generation of programmers is always failing to understand the amount of complexity here.